# Is there a way to forward authorization header through the Kubernetes API server proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I have some endpoint running on a pod inside of my Kubernetes cluster that is secured by basic auth. The normal way of accessing this pod through the API server would be:

```
https://{{ apiServer }}:{{ apiServerPort }}/api/v1/namespaces/{{ namespaceName }}/pods/{{ podName }}:{{ podPort }}/proxy/somepath
```

This works fine for endpoints that are not secured using Basic Auth, but when trying to access the secure endpoints, I get a 403 Forbidden every time because I can not specify two authentication headers and I already need to authenticate myself to the API server itself.
Is it possible to get those Basic Auth credentials forwarded to the pod or am I out of luck using the API server proxy?

Comment: Would you consider a solution with a sidecar container?

Comment: I would prefer one without it but how would it work with a sidecar container?

Comment: Hi did you managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: I know this is a late reply, but the best solution is just to have a pod running in the same namespace as the pod you are trying to access and then using it to make the requests, either by implementing your own solution of a proxy or simply sshing in and then using curl. If you do not need a permanent solution, simply port forwarding obviously also works.

Answer (score 1):

The working solution that I can think of is to use `kubectl port-forward`. As a result of that Kubernetes API server will establish a single http connection between your localhost and the resource running on your cluster. This will preserve all your client requests.

```
kubectl port-forward TYPE/NAME [options] LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_PORT
```

You can send the traffic to specific pod, use random local port or even specify local ip address use for forwarding.

You can read more about port forwarding [here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/container_debugging/port_forward_to_pods.html) and check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) example in the official kuberentes document.

If you want some alternatives you want to check [telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/).

PS. I tried to use a sidecar container with kubectl proxy but that did not work unfortunately.